# Xcode 7 Invalid image path error "AppIcon40x40"

Tags: ios, xcode

When i try to submit my iOS app using Xcode 7 i get this error during submission process:

[image]

images.xcassets file:
[image]

How to fix this issue
Thanks

Comment: see your CFBundleIconFile  in plist..

Comment: You're right i was assigning a wrong image size for 40*40 .Thank you!

Comment: Appreciate my ans...plz accept as answer..i think i waste my time

Answer (score 0):

Check your image size..40*40.suppose you added 39*39.display error like this..